# Wine - Using Native Icon for Program

Tags: wine, icons

When I run a wine program, the icon that is used in the Gnome Dock is the generic wine icon, so when I run Photoshop or League of Legends then the icon is the wine icon. (I'm not talking about the launcher - just the icon when I run it.)

Is there a way to make it so that when I launch a wine app, it uses the native icon rather than the generic wine icon?

Thanks,